# How to dynamically set MaxPageSize in UseOffsetPaging in Hot Chocolate?

Tags: pagination, hotchocolate

I want to dynamically set value to `MaxPageSize` in `UseOffsetPaging` rather than global setting.

How to do that?

Following are ways to set it, either globally OR per query. But what I want is, set it per query as shown in "Desired Result" block below. I do not want to go to cursor based pagination unless that is the only option.

Option-1:

```
[UseOffsetPaging(MaxPageSize = YOUR-VALUE)]
```

Option-2:

```
.SetPagingOptions(new PagingOptions
{
    IncludeTotalCount = true,
    MaxPageSize = int.MaxValue
})
```

Desired Result:

```
public partial class Query
{
  [UseOffsetPaging(MaxPageSize = take)] // Use take value which is coming from UI
  public async Task MyQuery(
          [GraphQLNonNullType]
          int skip,
          [GraphQLNonNullType]
          int take)
      => await doSomething;
}
```

Reference:

https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/pagination/#pagingoptions